# how to change column type counter to bigint in cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, cql

```sql
CREATE TABLE temp (
    id bigint PRIMARY KEY,
    date timestamp,
    count counter
)
```

I have a cassandra table^ . I want to change field type counter to `bigint`.

```sql
ALTER TABLE temp ALTER count TYPE counter ;
```

> ConfigurationException:  ErrorMessage code=2300 [Query invalid because
>   of configuration issue] message="Cannot change count from type bigint
>   to type counter: types are incompatible."

Answer (score 1):

Counters are treated as special types in Cassandra, which is why only counter types are allowed as non-key fields in counter tables.  NOTE: *Your table definition cannot be correct, as the `date` column needs to be a part of the key for the above definition to be valid.*

Your best option here, is to [COPY](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/copy_r.html) your table to a file from CQLSH:

```
aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow> COPY countertest TO 'countertest_20151028.csv' 
                             WITH DELIMITER='|' AND HEADER=true; 

3 rows exported in 0.008 seconds.
```

Then DROP and re CREATE your table with `count` as a BIGINT.  And finally run COPY (FROM) to re-import the data to your new table.